# Getting TwitterException while trying to post a tweet from code within eclipse

Tags: java, api, exception, twitter, twitter4j

- I am a newbie to twitter4j.
- I have registered an app with twitter, got ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret, Accesstoken and AccesstokenSecret.
- I followed steps mentioned [here](http://twitter4j.org/en/configuration.html), [here](http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html) and came with below code and tried to run from eclipse (JDK 1.7).

  ```
  import twitter4j.Status;
  import twitter4j.Twitter;
  import twitter4j.TwitterException;
  import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
  import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder;

  public class TweetMain {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
      cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
        .setOAuthConsumerKey("key")
        .setOAuthConsumerSecret("secret")
        .setOAuthAccessToken("token")
        .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("tokensecret");
      TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
      Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();     
      Status status;
      try {
          status = twitter.updateStatus("First Tweet from within Java code @java,@twitter, @twitter4j");
          System.out.println("Successfully updated the status to [" + status.getText() + "].");
      } catch (TwitterException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
  ```

  }
- I got below exception:

*Read timed out
Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:
    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=2fc5b7cb or
    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=0ea287e1
TwitterException{exceptionCode=[2fc5b7cb-0ea287e1 2fc5b7cb-0ea287b7], statusCode=-1, message=null, code=-1, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, version=4.0.4}*

- Please let me know where I have gone wrong. Thanks.

[UPDATE]: I am able to execute successfully from another system(debian). I shall recheck whether things go fine with my earlier system(windows7). Will update on what had gone wrong. Meanwhile, if anyone is aware of the Exception based on exception code, please answer/comment. Thanks.